# How to set and get Base property in chronometer c# newbe

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, chronometer

Hi I am new in android and c#. I would like to implement chronometer to my app and I stuck tring to write following java code in c#.

```
chrono.setBase(SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime());
```

I get information that i should set Base property like that

```
public virtual long Base { get; set; }
```

But how should I do that?
Could somebody help me how to make it works? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Chronometer chrono = new Chronometer();
chrono.Base = 1000;
```

Comment: ProTip: `Chronometer chrono = new Chronometer();` - it is considered a best practice not to repeat yourself. use `var` instead.